# How to add on "blur" event listeners to a website built by PSD2HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, onblur

Our website has been built by PSD2HTML.
Now we want to add some logic to a form that fires on "blur": we want to pre-populate another form field based on the field that the user has just populated.

If I add an event listener in a normal way such as by adding an `onblur` attribute to a tag

```
... onblur="alert('Focus lost');" ...
```

this code is never run and I never see the alert.

Instead, when I inspect the page that the browser receives I see the following event handler in the DOM Inspector for the "blur" event:

```
return function() {
    return f.apply(scope, arguments);
}
```

It seems this code is generated by the infamous JCF library that PSD2HTML supplies with all sites that they deliver.

How can I add my own code so that it's run on the "blur" event?

Answer (score 2):

Can you please provide an example of your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ so we could reproduce your issue.

The most recent version of JCF library is available here: https://github.com/w3co/jcf 
(Feel free to create an issue)

I've tried to add inline event handler `onblur="console.log('test')"` just like you've described above and it works perfectly in the current version. Here's working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/inferpse/gj30qu8s/).

I don't recommend using `alert` for testing focus/blur events because it switches focus from input field to modal dialog. Try `console.log` instead.

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble to investigate.
It turns out the problem was some other javascript code that was emulating HTML5 placeholder functionality. I've ripped out that code and added real HTML5 placeholders and a polyfill for backwards compatibility.